# Runtime Error during training with CUDA: Edge-Conditioned Convolution on Graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am relatively new to Python and currently trying to use CUDA within a specific neural net: Edge-Conditioned Convolution on Graphs, code can be found here https://github.com/mys007/ecc

I know that there are several questions like mine, but i wasn't able to solve my problem with them.

I would like to train a dataset with CUDA, but the process stops during the training of a (random) epoch with the following error:

```
File "./main.py", line 317, in <module>
main()
File "./main.py", line 219, in main
acc_train, loss, t_loader, t_trainer = train(epoch)
File "./main.py", line 150, in train
outputs = model(inputs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "/workspace/ECC_Test/models.py", line 105, in forward
input = module(input)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "/workspace/ECC_Test/ecc/GraphConvModule.py", line 173, in forward
return GraphConvFunction(self._in_channels, self._out_channels, idxn, idxe, degs, degs_gpu, self._edge_mem_limit)(input, weights)
File "/workspace/ECC_Test/ecc/GraphConvModule.py", line 69, in forward
cuda_kernels.conv_aggregate_fw(output.narrow(0,startd,numd), products.view(-1,self._out_channels), self._degs_gpu.narrow(0,startd,numd))
File "/workspace/ECC_Test/ecc/cuda_kernels.py", line 122, in conv_aggregate_fw
block=(CUDA_NUM_THREADS,1,1), grid=(GET_BLOCKS(w),n//blockDimY+1,1), stream=stream)            
File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 148, in cupy.cuda.function.Function.__call__
File "cupy/cuda/function.pyx", line 130, in cupy.cuda.function._launch
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 228, in cupy.cuda.driver.launchKernel
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 81, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 192, in cupy.cuda.driver.moduleUnload
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 81, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 192, in cupy.cuda.driver.moduleUnload
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 81, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 192, in cupy.cuda.driver.moduleUnload
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 81, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 192, in cupy.cuda.driver.moduleUnload
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 81, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 192, in cupy.cuda.driver.moduleUnload
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 81, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 192, in cupy.cuda.driver.moduleUnload
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 81, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 192, in cupy.cuda.driver.moduleUnload
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 81, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 192, in cupy.cuda.driver.moduleUnload
File "cupy/cuda/driver.pyx", line 81, in cupy.cuda.driver.check_status
cupy.cuda.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

Traceback is with "CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1"

Switching to CPU and deactivating CUDA works fine.

I am using SSH to access a Server with 4 Nvidia Tesla V100 32GB with driver version 410.104. CUDA 10.1 and Python 3.6.8 is installed.

Currently Pytorch is 1.1. Is the higher PyTorch version causing problems combined with CUDA 10.1? Or am I running out of memory on the GPU?

Comment: The error is likely caused by something wrong internally in the CUDA code in Pytorch

Comment: Hello @Sebastian, can you also share minimal example of your code ? Check here if you need guidance to create the example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your fast response,
I tried to follow the Traceback and the Error must occur somewhere in the "conv_aggregate_fw(dest, src, degs)" function of cuda_kernels.py, am I right? 

I believe it could be possible that there is something wrong with the allocation of indegrees from a given graph G and the following transfer to the Cuda() function (in GraphConvInfo.py)

Comment: Thanks for the link, @BertrandGazanion, I will try to create a code snippet